# Change a field based on a another field?

Tags: logstash

Logstash is receiving a `docs` JSON object which contains various types of docs.

```
{
  "docs": [
    {
      "_id": "project:A",
      "_rev": "project:1",
      "name": "secret",
      "children": ["item:A"]
    },
    {
      "_id": "item:A",
      "_rev": "item:1",
      "name": "secret"
    }
  ]
}
```

I want each doc with an `_id` starting with project to include matching children. The end result should be:

```
{
  "docs": [
    {
      "_id": "project:A",
      "_rev": "project:1",
      "name": "secret",
      "children": [{
        "_id": "item:A",
        "_rev": "item:1",
        "name": "secret"
    }]
    },
  ]
}
```

How can I achieve this?

Here is my conf file. I aven't been able to figure out how to solve this:

```
input {
  file {
   path => ["/home/logstash/logstash-testdata.json"]
   sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
   start_position => "beginning"
  }
}
filter {
  json {
    source => "message"
  }
  // ... ???
}
output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
  }
  stdout {
    codec => rubydebug
  }
}
```